# How to replace missing with previous missing with in 7 days

Tags: r

Hi I have df as below which value column has NA value
        how to replace NA values previous values with in last 7 days . if non NA value not found in last 7 days then no replacement for eg: there is no values for 10-01-2016 in last 7 days with that day

```
 Name   value   new_col
01-01-2016  NA     *NA*
02-01-2016  43
03-01-2016  NA     *43*
04-01-2016  NA     *43*
05-01-2016  NA     *43*
06-01-2016  NA     *43*
07-01-2016  NA     *43*
08-01-2016  NA     *43*
09-01-2016  NA     *43*
10-01-2016  NA     *NA*
11-01-2016  12
12-01-2016  33
13-01-2016  NA     *33*
14-01-2016  NA     *33*
```

we can fill with NA previous valu using ZOO lib

df<- transform(df, value  = na.locf(value))

df$new_col = ifelse(is.na(df$value) & (df$Name-7), na.locf(df$value), df$value)

Comment: df$new_col  = ifelse(is.na(df$value) & (df$Name-7),
                     na.locf(df$value),
                  df$value)

Comment: I also tried with above code but not find suitable answer as above

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `na.locf` from `zoo` package, with argument `maxgap`:

*(Note that we assume your data is arranged by date without missing holes in the serie)*

```
library(zoo)
df$new_col <- na.locf(df$value, maxgap = 7, na.rm = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks jlesuffleur  , getting "error as replacement has 13 rows, data has 14" and also what if dates are repeated

Comment: Sorry you have to set na.rm to FALSE

Comment: nice, I didn't know about this argument `maxgap`!

Comment: greate ,what if dates are repeated and i have tried with maxgap = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(df$Name-7)